# ASP.NET MVC 4 JSON Binding to the View Model - Nested object error

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have got the problem with json binding to the view model. Here is my code:

part of my ViewModels (AddressViewModel has more properties):

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
        [Display(Name = "Address_Town", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.PartyDetails))]
        public string Town { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Address_Country", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.PartyDetails))]
        public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country : EntityBase<string>
{
        public string Name { get; set; }

        protected override void Validate()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            {
                base.AddBrokenRule(new BusinessRule("CountryName", "Required"));
            }
        }
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#addAddress", function () {
            var jsonData = {
                "Town": $('#txt-Town').val(),
                "District": $('#txt-District').val(),
                "Street": $('#txt-Street').val(),
                "PostCode": $('#txt-PostCode').val(),
                "FlatNumber": $('#txt-FlatNumber').val(),
                "PremiseName": $('#txt-PremiseName').val(),
                "PremiseNumber": $('#txt-Premisenumber').val(),
                "Country": {
                    "Name": $('#txt-Country').val(),
                }
            };
            var addressData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Customer/SaveAddress',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: addressData,
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#addIndividualAddressDialog").data("kendoWindow").close();
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Failed");
                }

            });
        });
```

Header of controller:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SaveAddress(AddressViewModel addressViewModel)
```

This is what I see with firebug:

[image]

And this is what I see in VS:

[image]

As you can see Plain properties are binded correct but my nested object (Country) is null. I read a lot of different articles and I still don't know what I'm doing wrong. Help me please!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is from your action method parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveAddress(AddressViewModel addressViewModel)
```

As you use `JSON.stringify()`, you send a string to your controller, not an object! So, you need to do some works to achive your goal:

1) Change your action method parametter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveAddress(string addressViewModel)
```

2) Deserialize that string to an object - that is AddressViewModel:

```
IList<AddressViewModel> modelObj = new 
JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<AddressViewModel>>(addressViewModel);
```

So, your final action method should be like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveAddress(string addressViewModel)
{
    IList<AddressViewModel> modelObj = new 
    JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<AddressViewModel>>(addressViewModel);

    // do what you want with your model object ...
}
```

Comment: After changing action header and little changes in javascript it works!

Comment: This is not really an idiomatic solution as it will bypass the validation and binding capabilities of MVC. A much better solution is to add a JsonModelBinder and put this deserialization logic in there. If can be done by overriding a few methods in the DefaultModelBinder

Comment: If your values are inside a `form`, just serialize them and send them with ajax having the `contentType` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. If not, just wrap your input fields with a `form action="javascript:void(0);">` so that you can serialize the form with say [jQuery $.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and use as the payload of the request.

Answer (score 19):

You can keep your existing ActionMethod untouched without the need of json serializing:
In the client side create an object from your json:

```
JSON.parse(jsonData)
```

and send that in the $.ajax data property.

Or, instead of creating json, create an object:

```
var dataObject = new Object();
dataObject.Town = $('#txt-Town').val();
dataObject.District = $('#txt-District').val();
...
```

And again, send that object in the $.ajax data property.

Comment: this is the right answer to this question. there is no need to modify your server-side code, just send the right type of object it expects from the client.

Comment: No **JSON.parse(jsonData)** in ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: @hexadecimal, JSON.parse isn't part of MVC but JavaScript, that's why I wrote **client side**. MVC is server side!

Answer (score 3):

Actually the best option is just to remove the

```
var addressData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

line and send jsonData itself.  ASP.NET MVC will auto-bind it if it is an actual object and not just a string.

[Occam's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to answer for old thread.here you could work with `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult`

this is your signature

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SaveAddress(AddressViewModel addressViewModel)
```

it should look like

```
[HttpPost]
 public JsonResult SaveAddress(AddressViewModel addressViewModel)
 {
    return Json(status);
 }
```

the advantage would be if you use `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult` that u do not need to `Deserialize`

here is the link http://codeforcoffee.org/asp-net-mvc-intro-to-mvc-using-binding-json-objects-to-models/  from this link you can get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

OR you can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>();`

following is the code to deserialize the `JSON.stringify()` result

```
IList<AddressViewModel> modelObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<AddressViewModel>>(addressViewModel);
```

instead of

```
JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<AddressViewModel>>(addressViewModel);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
You must reference to Country object inside jsonData variable. The JSON POST binding will work correctly.

Old code:

    var jsonData = {
        "Town": $('#txt-Town').val(),
        "District": $('#txt-District').val(),
        "Street": $('#txt-Street').val(),
        "PostCode": $('#txt-PostCode').val(),
        "FlatNumber": $('#txt-FlatNumber').val(),
        "PremiseName": $('#txt-PremiseName').val(),
        "PremiseNumber": $('#txt-Premisenumber').val(),
        "Country": {
            "Name": $('#txt-Country').val(),
        }

New code:
    var jsonData = {
        "Town": $('#txt-Town').val(),
        "District": $('#txt-District').val(),
        "Street": $('#txt-Street').val(),
        "PostCode": $('#txt-PostCode').val(),
        "FlatNumber": $('#txt-FlatNumber').val(),
        "PremiseName": $('#txt-PremiseName').val(),
        "PremiseNumber": $('#txt-Premisenumber').val(),
        "Country.Name": $('#txt-Country').val(),
        }
```

Comment: Your idea works great in my case!