# Serialize form and submit with Backbone without a model

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, model-view-controller

This may not be possible, new to backbone. In short, I want to submit a form that wasn't created with backbone and prefer not to create a model just to submit the form.

Tried a few things like this:

```
    var formData = $('#AddNewUnitForm').serialize();  //or serializeArray()
    var contact = new Contact();
    contact.save(formData, { success: ect });
```

I am posting to an MVC app, this works fine using jquery's ajax, but the data is apparently submitted differently with backbone. The reason I want to use backbone is so I can return/use a standard validation model.

I've seen a few examples where a model is created, but considering I would just use it to submit the form, it seems like a waste vs just serializing the data.

Thanx ahead of time.

Comment: I'm afraid your question doesn't make sense to me. If you're going to use some kind of "standard validation model" (whatever that is), then you'll presumably need a Backbone model. Otherwise, what are you going to validate?

Comment: The response only needs to know the messages and which fields, it doesn't need to know the data. The data is being rendered via razor(mvc) which works fine, I don't see the need to create a second model of the data in js just to pass it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others that run into this. No it doesn't seem completely possible to pass in a json object with backbone and have the controller recognize it as an object because backbone stringify's it and causes extra formatting to be put in.

Here is the workaround that I found:

[ASP.NET MVC 4 JSON Binding to the View Model - Nested object error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373202/asp-net-mvc-4-json-binding-to-the-view-model-nested-object-error)