# ASP .NET MVC 4 binding json sent through ajax to custom class in controller not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveCompensationComponent(int agencyId, CompensationComponentAllData compensationComponent)
    {
        int? id = _dmsCompensation.SaveCompensationComponent(agencyId, compensationComponent);
        return Json(id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Definition of the CompensationComponentAllData class:

```
public class CompensationComponentAllData
{
    some properties

    ...

    public CompensationObject CompensationElement { get; set; }

    public CompensationObject CompensationBasis { get; set; }

    ...        

    some properties

    ...
}
```

CompensationObject class:

```
public class CompensationObject
{
    some properties

    ...

    public ActivityData ByActivity { get; set; }

    ...        

    some properties

    ...
}
```

ActivityData class:

```
public class ActivityData
{
    some properties

    ...

    public List<int> GoalCategories { get; set; }

    public List<int> Policies { get; set; }

    ...        

    some properties

    ...


    public ActivityData() { }

    public ActivityData(CompensationObjectByActivity record) {

        ...
    }
}
```

In javascript I create appropriate objects and send that through ajax (contentType: 'application/json' and JSON.stringify used before sending data). Everything is correctly sent to server because I executed following code in the controller:

```
HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var jsonStringData = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

And jsonStringData had correct value:

```
"{\"agencyId\":\"332\",\"compensationComponent\":{\"Id\":431,\"CompensationComponentInfoId\":509,\"AgencyJobPositionId\":\"306\",\"Name\":\"ggggggg44\",\"Description\":\"fdssssssss\",\"CompensationComponentImpactLevelId\":\"1\",\"CompensationProductionTypeId\":\"1\",\"CompensationFrequency\":{\"Id\":\"1\"},\"CompensationDateTypeId\":\"3\",\"EffectiveDate\":\"06/10/2015\",\"BasisDifferentThanElement\":false,\"CompensationElement\":{\"ObjectTypeId\":\"3\",\"ByActivity\":{\"CompensationAttributeId\":\"21\",\"UnitsId\":\"3\",\"PoliciesLevel\":\"Individual Company/Policy\",\"Policies\":[\"572\",\"139\",\"138\"],\"VerificationLevelId\":\"1\"}},\"CompensationBasis\":{\"ObjectTypeId\":\"3\",\"ByActivity\":{\"CompensationAttributeId\":\"21\",\"UnitsId\":\"3\",\"PoliciesLevel\":\"Individual Company/Policy\",\"Policies\":[\"572\",\"139\",\"138\"],\"VerificationLevelId\":\"1\"}},\"CompensationStructureId\":\"2\",\"CompensationRateId\":\"1\",\"FixedValue\":\"10.00\",\"UseChargeback\":false}}"
```

Now problem is that after binding compensationComponent.CompensationElement.ByActivity.Policies has a null value even though it should be a list with 3 elements.

What makes me even more confused is that in the same time compensationComponent.CompensationBasis.ByActivity.Policies is bound correctly. Also compensationComponent.CompensationElement.ByActivity.GoalCategories is bound correctly too.

EDIT:

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: callback,
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        ...
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    cache: cache
});
```

If I remove JSON.stringify and try something as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373202/asp-net-mvc-4-json-binding-to-the-view-model-nested-object-error) I get error in binding so 500 is just returned.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried changing the JSON format from `"Policies":["572","139","138"]` to `"Policies":[572,139,138]` so it is posted as a number instead of as strings?

Comment: Do you use custom model binder for this object?

Comment: @br4d when do you mean? I have list of ints in js but stringify converst everything to string. Also if that would be a problem then compensationComponent.CompensationBasis.ByActivity.Policies wouldn't be bound too.

Comment: @Mariusz I don't use custom model binder.

Comment: Try to remove CompensationBasis from JSON and check if second object will be bound correctly maybe it will give us some hint.

Comment: You can also check this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373202/asp-net-mvc-4-json-binding-to-the-view-model-nested-object-error I don't see this issue in mvc 5

Comment: @Mariusz when I removed CompensationBasis from json it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a little bit strange that you want to receive part of the JSON as method parameters. I think you need to introduce a class for root object:

```
public class CompensationModel
{
    public int AgencyId { get; set; }
    public CompensationComponentAllData CompensationComponent { get; set; }
}
```

And your controller method will take this class as a parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveCompensationComponent(CompensationModel model)
```

I suggest you to use services like [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/), let's computer does the boring work.

And few comments about JSON that you send. `JSON.stringify` doesn't change types:

```
JSON.stringify({a: [1, 2, 3]}) // -> "{"a":[1,2,3]}"
JSON.stringify({a: ["1", "2", "3"]}) // -> "{"a":["1","2","3"]}"
```

So if you get strings in your JSON that menas that javascript values are of type `string`. In C# models you expect to have `int`, so you might consider to convert data in javascript, though MVC is smart enough to convert these values.

Comment: I tried like that and now it's not even setting the policies for CompensationBasis. When I put agencyId to root model it was acting same like before root model.

Comment: For now I made a workaround by putting policies list to one place higher in hierarchy and it works but I would really like to discover why is this happening,

Comment: I updated my answer. Check `CompensationModel` class and `SaveCompensationComponent` method parameters.