# Server validation - response message?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, httpresponse

I am coding server validation with C# and HttpResponseMessage. I need to send response back to the client with certain message, that the data sent is not valid. Which response code should I choose from this list?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx

Could I also customize the message so that I know which field got invalid data?

Note: MVC 4, Visual Studio 2010.

Here is my post function:

```
// POST api/Default1
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostUserProfile(HttpRequestMessage  req)
    {
        UserProfile up = new UserProfile();
        string jsonContent = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            up = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfile>(jsonContent);
            if (up.userName.Length <= 50 &&
                up.email.Length <= 60)
            {

                db.UserProfiles.Add(up);
                db.SaveChanges();

                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, up);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = up.UserId }));
                return response;
            }
            else 
            {
                // finish the server validation
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, up);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = up.UserId }));
                return response;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 400 (Bad Request) is the one. Note that `ModelState.IsValid` is always true because you are not using Model Binding at all. Also you should really [use the built-in model binding capabilities of MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373202/asp-net-mvc-4-json-binding-to-the-view-model-nested-object-error).

Comment: `req.CreateResponse(...)` should solve your problem. You can respond with whatever content you like, including JSON with invalid field and explanations of what exactly is wrong and how to fix it. For this purpose you better create a new class holding such properties like `string ErrorMessage` and pass inside the `.CreateResponse(...)` as a parameters.

Comment: Opinion only, I would return code 400-Bad request

Comment: BadRequest - 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people suggested BadRequest which is Http message 400:

> Equivalent to HTTP status 400. BadRequest indicates that the request could not be understood by the server. BadRequest is sent when no other error is applicable, or if the exact error is unknown or does not have its own error code.

I don't think its suitable in this case since the browser does not see it as error, as if I sent OK message back to the client.

I think NotFound is more appropriate:

> Equivalent to HTTP status 404. NotFound indicates that the requested resource does not exist on the server.

The browser sees it as error and therefore sent to the error handler in the  jQuery AJAX object. So you can properly handle it, i.e update some message box in the html to let the user know that the server/database simply does not contain that resource or row in the table.